# find a transformation matix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose that $X$ is an $n \times k$ matrix with $n>k$ and $\text{rank}(X)=\ell < k$.
Consider a non-singular $k \times k$ matrix $R=[R_1, R_2]$ where $R_1$ is $k \times \ell$ and $R_2$ is $k \times (k-\ell)$ that satisfies

$\text{rank}(XR_1)=\ell$  and $XR_2=0.$

How can I find such an $R$ matrix? Are there explicit solution for $R$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Consider SVD decomposition.
$$X=U\begin{bmatrix}D & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}V^T$$

$D \in \mathbb{R}^{l \times l}$ is diagonal and has decreasing singular values, and both $U \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $V \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times k}$ are orthogonal matrix.

You should be be able to construct $R$ from there.

Comment: Thank you very much! The answer is $R_1=V_1$ where $V=[V_1, V_2]$. However, I'm wondering if this is unique or not. By using  Gaussian elimination, I found another $R_1$ that is different from the one obtained from SVD. So, I'm wondering which I should use...

Comment: it is not unique. Regarding the choices, it depends on your purpose, is the concern speed for a lot of $X$? if so, pick one that cost less to obtain.